# Error: Table 'student' already exists Error Code: ER_TABLE_EXISTS_ERROR

Tags: mysql, sql, database, popsql

SHOWING ERROR IN POSQL

CREATE TABLE student (
student_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(20),
major VARCHAR(20)
);

Answer (score 1):

First Drop Previously Created Table by

```
Drop Table student
```

And Then Execute Your Query

```
CREATE TABLE student ( student_id INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(20), major VARCHAR(20) );
```